# Jquery function in Ruby on Rails application clear input field when i want replace characters

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Input in my Ruby on rails application has type="number" but Edge don't recognize type when input has ',' (comma). I'd like to swap it dynamically.When user input ',' on Edge i replace it to '.', but when i type ',' my whole input disappear.

It's my jquery function to this action

```
$("[name^='price_normal']").on("input", function () {
          if (/EDGE\/\d./i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
              var dInput = this.value;
              dInput = dInput.replace(/[,]/,'.');
              console.log(dInput);
              this.value = dInput;
          } else {

          }
      });
```

And html

```
 <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="1000.00" name="price_normal<%= p.id %>" value="" />
```

log from browser

```
{"notifyType":"consoleItemLog","message":{"message":"","styles":"","hasFormatString":true,"fileUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:3000/prices","lineNumber":2319,"columnNumber":15}}
```

Comment: What does this show: `console.log(dInput)`?

Comment: I'm curious why would you change comma to decimal. It changes the meaning completely. `123,456` is not same as `123.456`.

Comment: When i input ',' then log look like above (log from browser) when i input other character it log my input, i'd like to change comma to decimal becouse Edge not recognise numeber with comma like a number and i have error for user, for example in opera or chrome i can input number with comma and decimal without error

Comment: @akaoD Can't you use text_field tag instead of number field?